# How to unlink files one by one until directory is empty

Tags: php

I have this script that gets the first file name from a directory, with this variable deletes a line from a file (register file) and then deletes the actual file from the directory, the thing is that I need this action to take place only if there are files in the directory and in case of more than one file the action continues taking place with the second, third files, and so on until the directory is empty... how? help please....

```
// Register file
$registerf = "results/register.php";

// Get the firs file name
$firstFile = scandir("results/todel/")[2];

// Delete it from register file
$regex = "'/$firstFile/d'";
$cmd = "sed -i $regex $registerf";
shell_exec($cmd);

// Actually delete the file from directory
unlink("results/todel/".$firstFile);
```

Comment: Loop through all the files: `foreach ($file in scandir("results/todel/"))`

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, this whas the way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Register file
$registerf = "results/register.php";
//go through each file in dir
foreach(scandir("results/todel/") as $file){

    if ($file != "." && $file != ".."){

        // Delete it from register file
        $regex = "'/$file/d'";
        $cmd = "sed -i $regex $registerf";
        shell_exec($cmd);

        // Actually delete the file from directory if it's a file
        unlink("results/todel/".$file);

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, based on @Barmar comment and your help I could arrive to set this solution

Comment: I had to do a little adjustment though, just before the $regex variable I had to add this line `if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {`

Comment: I have updated the solution according to your comment, Andrés Chandia.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($handle = opendir('/mydir/')) {

    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {

        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {

            unlink("/mydir/".$file);
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```

Hope this may helps you

Comment: You need to concatenate `$file` to the directory name.